# Convert LOG4J >> SLF4J + logback

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, logback

I am currently tasked with changing all occurrences of LOG4J to SLF4J including logback when necessary.

I already managed converting all the old log4j.xml to logback.xml and to force the usage of logback appenders, however, I just discovered a line in the code that I can't translate to slf4j / logback just yet.

Googling the issue didn't turn up anything usable, so I hope that some of you can help me here.

The code line is:

```
 for ( final Enumeration e = LogManager.getLoggerRepository().getCurrentLoggers();  e.hasMoreElements(); ) {
    final Logger logger = (Logger) e.nextElement();
        final Level level = logger.getLevel();
        if ( level != null ) {
            final String name = logger.getName();
            final Integer intLvl = new Integer( level.toInt() );
            logLevelLocal.put( name, intLvl );
 }
```

The main issue seems to be the LogManager class. I couldn't come up with any logback equivalent.  Does anyone know if there is something similar in logback or if there's some kind of workaround?

Best regards,
daZza

edit:

1:

```
public static void toggleLogging( final boolean enable ) {

    if ( enable ) {
        Properties.LOGGING_ENABLED = Boolean.TRUE;
        System.out.println( ConstantsCommon.SYSOUT_PREFIX + LOG_LOGGING + LOG_ON );

        for ( final Iterator it = ConstantsCommon.LOGGER_LEVELS.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            final String logger = (String) it.next();
            final int logLevel = ( (Integer) ConstantsCommon.LOGGER_LEVELS.get( logger ) ).intValue();
            ( (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger( logger ) ).setLevel( Level.toLevel( logLevel ) );
        }
        root.setLevel( Level.toLevel( ConstantsCommon.LOGGER_ROOTLEVEL ) );

    } else {
        Properties.LOGGING_ENABLED = Boolean.FALSE;
        System.out.println( ConstantsCommon.SYSOUT_PREFIX + LOG_LOGGING + LOG_OFF );

        for ( final Iterator it = ConstantsCommon.LOGGER_LEVELS.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            final String logger = (String) it.next();
            ( (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger( logger ) ).setLevel( Level.OFF );
        }
        root.setLevel( Level.OFF );
    }
}
```

2:

```
 public void setLogLevel( final String loggerName, final int level ) throws ModelRemoteException {
    if ( ( level == Priority.ALL_INT ) || ( level == Priority.DEBUG_INT ) || ( level == Priority.ERROR_INT )
            || ( level == Priority.FATAL_INT ) || ( level == Priority.INFO_INT ) || ( level == Priority.WARN_INT )
            || ( level == Priority.OFF_INT ) ) {
        final Level targetLevel = Level.toLevel( level );

        final Logger logger = ( (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger( loggerName ) );
        if ( logger != null ) {

            ( (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger( loggerName ) ).setLevel( targetLevel );

            ConstantsCommon.LOGGER_LEVELS.put( loggerName, new Integer( level ) );
        } else {
            throw new ModelRemoteException( PropertiesErrorCodes.ec2024 );
        }
    } else {
        throw new ModelRemoteException( PropertiesErrorCodes.ec2025 );
    }
}
```

Comment: What is inside the loop?  Usually the main application is completely unaware of the logger configuration so there is most likely something interesting happening here.

Comment: Edited. Don't think it's relevant though. I just need the logback "translation" for LogManager.getLoggerRepository().getCurrentLoggers()

Comment: Looks like you are creating a map of lognames->level which to me sounds like a debug tool (which should be moved outside your application and into the logger configuration in my opinion) or an optimization of the test if the logger is enabled (which is much easier in slf4j).

Comment: It's not really in the application itself. This method is located in a .java class that only holds common constants, so most of the class just looks like  public static final XXX = YYY. In the end that lognames->level map is created. Are you saying there is no possibility to "translate" the LogManager class to slf4j / logback?

Comment: Trying to translate this piece of code without context might be the wrong approach. What it does is create a map of all loggers to their respective level (as an Integer). But what is it used for? Why is this map created and what does the non-utility code do with it? A direct translation might be impossible, but maybe it isn't even needed if what you eventually do with the map can be handled by slf4j/logback natively.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not really into the code myself, as it was just delivered to me and I'm not a pro in Java either :) From what I can tell when examining the call hierarchy, the map is used by three non util functions. The first just returns the map (which is saved as a constant LOGGER_LEVELS). The second one seems to be able to set a different level and I think the third kinda toggles the logging component on or off. I added both methods to the OP. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through tons of documentations and forum posts again, I think that I've found a working solution in logback.

Instead of using the (nonexistent) LogManager class I am now using the logback LoggerContext:

```
LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
```

And instead of using getLoggerRepository().getCurrentLoggers() I switched to using

```
lc.getLoggerList();
```

Comment: That might be a way to mimick what your code did with log4j. But keep in mind that this kind of code once again ties your codebase to a specific logging implementation, a situation slf4j is specifically designed to prevent (if used right). To me it seems wrong to have methods in the code to toggle logging on/off and change levels, especially if done for a specific logging framework. That kind of stuff should be done via the configuration-files, which already allow changing of logging and log-levels on the fly. The running program itself should not (have to) intervene here.