# Convert LOG4J Priority.class >> SLF4J + logback

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, logback

I am currently tasked with changing all occurrences of LOG4J to SLF4J including logback when necessary.

I already managed converting all the old log4j.xml to logback.xml and to force the usage of logback appenders, however, I just discovered a line in the code that I can't translate to slf4j / logback just yet.

Googling the issue didn't turn up anything usable, so I hope that some of you can help me here.

The code line is:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Priority;
```

Does anyone know the equivalent to the Priority class in slf4j? Would be greatly appreciated...

I already checked the org.slf4j.*, ch.qos.logback.core.* and ch.qos.logback.classic.* packages but this class seems to be missing.

best regards,
daZza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent would be Level. Priority was what level became and has since become deprecated:

http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/class-use/Priority.html
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Priority.html

Comment: Glad it helped. Good luck with the rest of your migration. :)

Comment: Thanks. Got most of it done, only one problem remains: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22064173 Do you have an idea on that too?